# How to store the multiple values of selected checkbox in database as foreign key in laravel?

Tags: php, database, laravel, checkbox

I have admin_report table to store report option created by admin and report table to store data after user report any post. Admin_report_id(checkbox option) is foreign key in report table.

How to store the multiple values of selected checkbox in database as foreign key?

Here is the error: its not passing the id of checkbox

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`fyp`.`report`, CONSTRAINT `report_admin_report_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`admin_report_id`) REFERENCES `admin_report` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `report` (`report`, `postqs_id`, `admin_report_id`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (ss, 18, 18, 5, 2018-01-12 11:34:30, 2018-01-12 11:34:30))

**controller:**

```
        public function store(Request $request,Postqs $postqs,$id,Report  $report, Admin_report $admin_report)
    {

    foreach ($report as $key => $report) {
        $data = $request->all();

       $data = $request->all();
       $user = auth()->user();
       $user->report()->create([
        'report' => $data['report'],'postqs_id' => $id,'admin_report_id'=>$id


        ]);
    }
```

**Blade:**

```
  @foreach ($admin_report as $key => $report)
<label class="container2">

  <input type="checkbox" name="report[{{$report->id}}]"> 
  {{$report>admin_report}}

 </select>
<span class="checkmark"></span>
 </label>
  @endforeach
```

**Relationship :**

```
       public function report(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Report');
       }


    public function postqs(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\Postqs','postqs_id','id');
    }
```

Comment: there is no row with the id equal to value of `admin_report_id`  in `admin_report ` table

Comment: @MahdiYounesi   u meant in blade? isit correct?
<input type="checkbox" name="report[{{$report->id}}]"

  {{($report['admin_report_id->id'] == $report->id ) ? ' selected' : '' }}> 

  {{$report->admin_report}}

Comment: create a table with columns user_id, post_id, report_id. each report id indicates to report item. the combination of three columns is primary key.

Comment: @Amin   i already create that which is the report table..now im stucked in the storing data part..